# unable to solve the routing error while using devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise gem, I had install the gem also but I am still getting error as below:

```
no route matches[Get] "/dhwani_app"
```

Comment: please provide detailed stack trace along with `routes.rb`

Comment: We really need to see the entire routes file, or a route trace, as per swap.nil's request :)

Answer (score 0):

In your routes try adding

"devise_for :(whatever your model is)" but obviously don't put the quotations in